# Error cannot open file 'mfc80u.lib' in Visual studio Community 2013

Tags: c++

I have an existing solution created with VS2005.  And currently I am using Visual Studio Community 2013.  When attempting to link, I get the following error:

> Error 3   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc80u.lib'

We do not specifically specify this as a dependency. But we have set "Use MFC in a Shared DLL" for Use of MFC.

There is `mfc120u.lib` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\lib` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the old VS2005 mfc runtime is still being linked.
This is what you can do:

- Check the libraries that are present in Configuration properties->Linker->Input
- When that does not resolve the problem, open your .vcxproj file in a text editor and search for 'mfc80u.lib', and remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!!!!


1. 'sx80lc32.lib' is present in the Configuration properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies


2. Opened .vcxproj file in a text editor and search for 'mfc80u.lib', but it is not there.

Comment: Might be that sx80lc32.lib is the one that links to mfc80u.lib.

Comment: Sorry!!! It is not working. 
I have removed sx80lc32.lib from the onfiguration properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.

And also removed it from .vcproj and .vcxproj.

Still it is giving the same error.